# Bootstrap - How do I move this column to the bottom?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get this column to be aligned next to the Card box and have the project name right next to it. I'm trying to make it responsive so I feel that I need to have that column at the bottom of the jumbotron. How can I do that? (see picture). Thank you to anyone who replies, I'm still trying to learn bootstrap and CSS.
[image]

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("src\app\assets\image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.whiteColorText {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
aside .box {
  position: relative;
}
aside .card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundInformation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jumbotron col ">
        <!-- style="top: 4rem; right: -20em; font-size: 22px;" -->

        <!--  position-relative offset-md-8 -->
        <p
          
        class="col-6-md whiteColorText "
        >
          {{projectName}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <aside class="col-4">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="https://picsum.photos/600/200"
              alt="Card image cap"
            />

            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="col">
                <h5 class="card-title"><b> About</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  {{ projectDescription }}
                </p>

                <h5 class="card-title"><b> Team Members </b></h5>
                test1 <br />
                test2 <br />
                test3
                <h5 class="card-title"><b> Interests</b></h5>
                <!-- 
                <ul *ngFor="let item of interests">
                  {{
                    item
                  }}
                </ul> -->
                <ul *ngFor="let item of interests">
                  <div class="centerObjects">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Music'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> music_note </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Technology'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> desktop_mac</mat-icon>
                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Sports'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> sports_football</mat-icon>
                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Art'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> create </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Fashion'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> checkroom </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Gaming'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false">
                        sports_esports
                      </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Education'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> menu_book</mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Business'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> business</mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <span> </span>
                  </div>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="col">
        itaque quae, minus error blanditiis corrupti optio ullam quidem
        necessitatibus. Nulla eveniet unde quod deserunt cupiditate expedita
        ducimus reiciendis doloribus, quae officia iusto quo, totam! Quae et
        eius quisquam. Vitae quaerat, odit harum nam expedita rem mollitia et,
        nihil rerum eos aut quas nostrum adipisci! Laborum nesciunt, ad saepe
        voluptatum doloribus aspernatur dolorem! Ratione rerum, in obcaecati,
        aliquam est dolor. Eos aliquam pariatur accusantium animi, reiciendis
        placeat ducimus beatae sunt reprehenderit numquam unde consequuntur sint
        asperiores, quasi saepe vero officiis laudantium. Doloribus possimus
        quidem reprehenderit aliquid nemo dolorum perspiciatis laudantium
        expedita numquam omnis! Necessitatibus consequuntur debitis minus vel
        voluptate minima fugit numquam voluptatibus assumenda ab, omnis quasi
        ipsam possimus aut suscipit, temporibus odio quam sit, nemo sed sapiente
        facilis corrupti blanditiis. Debitis, quod? Quo, impedit nam nihil
        cumque vel magnam facilis accusantium distinctio. Doloremque consequatur
        aliquid id? Vero repudiandae delectus laboriosam mollitia provident
        odio, numquam earum sequi deleniti recusandae nobis expedita quisquam
        nihil ipsa, nam temporibus asperiores. Distinctio ratione ab minima
        optio, in numquam perspiciatis asperiores velit perferendis pariatur
        voluptate deleniti, veritatis enim ullam nam reprehenderit ipsam sed!
        Temporibus molestiae accusamus impedit facilis amet in sed quae facere
        sequi repellat quas consequatur aperiam ipsam mollitia, molestias, sit
        delectus laudantium aspernatur! Fuga fugit veritatis magnam similique
        laboriosam, enim sequi esse quibusdam vero sit laudantium. Repellendus
        et, porro! Possimus recusandae doloribus quae unde repellendus aperiam
        eligendi qui maiores tempore! Nesciunt numquam quis nihil, quam sequi
        cumque quo, natus amet veniam excepturi, repellendus ipsum iure
        doloremque? Nostrum cupiditate cum necessitatibus officiis harum
        adipisci cumque vero accusamus autem provident quas, ex assumenda
        deserunt a fugit quibusdam consequuntur error ratione placeat
        perspiciatis fugiat at! Nihil minima fugiat nostrum odio nulla a,
        placeat ipsa magnam ad blanditiis illo, aliquam id earum ratione vitae
        consectetur, aspernatur adipisci soluta ut reiciendis quisquam
        laboriosam. Similique iusto dolor dignissimos architecto animi officia,
        facere quidem, sapiente tempore atque sed quisquam! Odio, nemo excepturi
        quasi exercitationem. Ipsa saepe quod reiciendis perferendis rerum
        officia vero delectus rem placeat commodi vel qui ab nisi doloremque
        esse accusantium, inventore similique! Culpa, alias tempora dolorum
        nulla veniam eveniet, ea, recusandae omnis quas cupiditate eaque ullam
        beatae labore quaerat repellendus explicabo illum impedit tempore
        adipisci praesentium consequatur in! Perspiciatis culpa ullam totam
        consequatur unde. Harum itaque aliquid, esse fugit ipsam ipsum qui
        dolore natus nulla temporibus, suscipit velit omnis. Voluptates labore
        impedit consequuntur vel enim sunt iste, neque inventore explicabo et
        illum expedita sint. Porro minus omnis enim, quo reprehenderit facere
        iusto corporis vero, perspiciatis, suscipit perferendis commodi
        accusantium laboriosam aliquam consectetur non soluta voluptatibus
        repellat nostrum magnam ullam aliquid nisi unde. Sint, porro velit,
        eligendi ea suscipit qui tenetur quos esse. Aspernatur, autem ullam
        fugiat quod magni, vitae porro perspiciatis delectus. Aperiam, quos,
        maiores? Laudantium, optio omnis perspiciatis obcaecati itaque excepturi
        voluptas, culpa atque accusantium veritatis odio dolores saepe illo
        incidunt aut eaque modi nihil laborum. Tempora eum placeat omnis
        reiciendis cupiditate harum, odio voluptatem numquam corrupti illum
        minus dignissimos cum optio. Autem libero cupiditate qui id obcaecati
        repudiandae quasi, veniam temporibus ut facilis voluptatibus hic quod
        tempore iste eligendi labore et, porro dolore. Voluptates sit, ullam
        commodi a amet. Dolorum laboriosam harum quod cupiditate in rem
        veritatis saepe tempore, cumque commodi deleniti voluptate, cum quasi
        nesciunt incidunt temporibus expedita aut, quisquam omnis facilis odit
        sit assumenda. Labore impedit cumque eveniet quae, provident velit, eos,
        rem enim esse, natus nisi voluptatum non in. Adipisci sit excepturi,
        aperiam. Mollitia assumenda repudiandae ipsam saepe, maxime rerum,
        fugiat! Ducimus, beatae ex aliquid! Earum ab voluptas eligendi hic
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include all your HTML. This is only the left left `column`.

Comment: Hi, @Simplicius I added the full html. It looks pretty weird in the Snippet though for some reason. Thank you for helping in advance. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was, that the `p` element was placed inside a totally different `row`.
You need to imagine it kinda like this.

```
-------------------------------
           [row-1]
-------------------------------
         | [row-2]        
         |
[card]   |               [text]
         |
-------------------------------
```

So what I did now is, I moved our infamous `p` from the *first* `row` to the *second* `row`, which consists out of *two* `columns` and put it in the *second* one. So now its next to the `card` and above the text.

```
<div class="backgroundInformation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style=" height: 100px">
      <div class="jumbotron col ">
        <!-- style="top: 4rem; right: -20em; font-size: 22px;" -->

        <!--  position-relative offset-md-8 -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <aside class="col-4">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="https://picsum.photos/600/200"
              alt="Card image cap"
            />

            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="col">
                <h5 class="card-title"><b> About</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  {{ projectDescription }}
                </p>

                <h5 class="card-title"><b> Team Members </b></h5>
                test1 <br />
                test2 <br />
                test3
                <h5 class="card-title"><b> Interests</b></h5>
                <!-- 
                <ul *ngFor="let item of interests">
                  {{
                    item
                  }}
                </ul> -->
                <ul *ngFor="let item of interests">
                  <div class="centerObjects">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Music'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> music_note </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Technology'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> desktop_mac</mat-icon>
                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Sports'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> sports_football</mat-icon>
                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Art'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> create </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Fashion'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> checkroom </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Gaming'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false">
                        sports_esports
                      </mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Education'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> menu_book</mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="item === 'Business'">
                      <mat-icon aria-hidden="false"> business</mat-icon>

                      {{ item }}
                    </ng-container>
                    <span> </span>
                  </div>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="col">
        <div class="block" style="background-color: transparent;">
          <p class="col-6-md whiteColorText " >
            {{projectName}}
          </p>
        </div>
       <div style="background-color: #fff;">
          itaque quae, minus error blanditiis corrupti optio ullam quidem
        necessitatibus. Nulla eveniet unde quod deserunt cupiditate expedita
        ducimus reiciendis doloribus, quae officia iusto quo, totam! Quae et
        eius quisquam. Vitae quaerat, odit harum nam expedita rem mollitia et,
        nihil rerum eos aut quas nostrum adipisci! Laborum nesciunt, ad saepe
        voluptatum doloribus aspernatur dolorem! Ratione rerum, in obcaecati,
        aliquam est dolor. Eos aliquam pariatur accusantium animi, reiciendis
        placeat ducimus beatae sunt reprehenderit numquam unde consequuntur sint
        asperiores, quasi saepe vero officiis laudantium. Doloribus possimus
        quidem reprehenderit aliquid nemo dolorum perspiciatis laudantium
        expedita numquam omnis! Necessitatibus consequuntur debitis minus vel
        voluptate minima fugit numquam voluptatibus assumenda ab, omnis quasi
        ipsam possimus aut suscipit, temporibus odio quam sit, nemo sed sapiente
        facilis corrupti blanditiis. Debitis, quod? Quo, impedit nam nihil
        cumque vel magnam facilis accusantium distinctio. Doloremque consequatur
        aliquid id? Vero repudiandae delectus laboriosam mollitia provident
        odio, numquam earum sequi deleniti recusandae nobis expedita quisquam
        nihil ipsa, nam temporibus asperiores. Distinctio ratione ab minima
        optio, in numquam perspiciatis asperiores velit perferendis pariatur
        voluptate deleniti, veritatis enim ullam nam reprehenderit ipsam sed!
        Temporibus molestiae accusamus impedit facilis amet in sed quae facere
        sequi repellat quas consequatur aperiam ipsam mollitia, molestias, sit
        delectus laudantium aspernatur! Fuga fugit veritatis magnam similique
        laboriosam, enim sequi esse quibusdam vero sit laudantium. Repellendus
        et, porro! Possimus recusandae doloribus quae unde repellendus aperiam
        eligendi qui maiores tempore! Nesciunt numquam quis nihil, quam sequi
        cumque quo, natus amet veniam excepturi, repellendus ipsum iure
        doloremque? Nostrum cupiditate cum necessitatibus officiis harum
        adipisci cumque vero accusamus autem provident quas, ex assumenda
        deserunt a fugit quibusdam consequuntur error ratione placeat
        perspiciatis fugiat at! Nihil minima fugiat nostrum odio nulla a,
        placeat ipsa magnam ad blanditiis illo, aliquam id earum ratione vitae
        consectetur, aspernatur adipisci soluta ut reiciendis quisquam
        laboriosam. Similique iusto dolor dignissimos architecto animi officia,
        facere quidem, sapiente tempore atque sed quisquam! Odio, nemo excepturi
        quasi exercitationem. Ipsa saepe quod reiciendis perferendis rerum
        officia vero delectus rem placeat commodi vel qui ab nisi doloremque
        esse accusantium, inventore similique! Culpa, alias tempora dolorum
        nulla veniam eveniet, ea, recusandae omnis quas cupiditate eaque ullam
        beatae labore quaerat repellendus explicabo illum impedit tempore
        adipisci praesentium consequatur in! Perspiciatis culpa ullam totam
        consequatur unde. Harum itaque aliquid, esse fugit ipsam ipsum qui
        dolore natus nulla temporibus, suscipit velit omnis. Voluptates labore
        impedit consequuntur vel enim sunt iste, neque inventore explicabo et
        illum expedita sint. Porro minus omnis enim, quo reprehenderit facere
        iusto corporis vero, perspiciatis, suscipit perferendis commodi
        accusantium laboriosam aliquam consectetur non soluta voluptatibus
        repellat nostrum magnam ullam aliquid nisi unde. Sint, porro velit,
        eligendi ea suscipit qui tenetur quos esse. Aspernatur, autem ullam
        fugiat quod magni, vitae porro perspiciatis delectus. Aperiam, quos,
        maiores? Laudantium, optio omnis perspiciatis obcaecati itaque excepturi
        voluptas, culpa atque accusantium veritatis odio dolores saepe illo
        incidunt aut eaque modi nihil laborum. Tempora eum placeat omnis
        reiciendis cupiditate harum, odio voluptatem numquam corrupti illum
        minus dignissimos cum optio. Autem libero cupiditate qui id obcaecati
        repudiandae quasi, veniam temporibus ut facilis voluptatibus hic quod
        tempore iste eligendi labore et, porro dolore. Voluptates sit, ullam
        commodi a amet. Dolorum laboriosam harum quod cupiditate in rem
        veritatis saepe tempore, cumque commodi deleniti voluptate, cum quasi
        nesciunt incidunt temporibus expedita aut, quisquam omnis facilis odit
        sit assumenda. Labore impedit cumque eveniet quae, provident velit, eos,
        rem enim esse, natus nisi voluptatum non in. Adipisci sit excepturi,
        aperiam. Mollitia assumenda repudiandae ipsam saepe, maxime rerum,
        fugiat! Ducimus, beatae ex aliquid! Earum ab voluptas eligendi hic
       </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You probably still got to fiddle a little with your CSS to make it good looking, but it's now "physically" next to your `card` element.

You maybe add `display: block;` as well as some `margin` or `padding` to the `p` element.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that helped a lot with my understanding of how that works. I still have a question though. I was wondering if there would be a way for this to be inside of the jumbotron. Currently, it's below it. I just added a picture to the end of the post. Is there a way to do that with CSS currently? By the way, I can't thank you enough for replying to the comment and helping me.

Comment: @Jacob. Sure. I edited my code, just copy & paste it. I removed the first row though, since it wouldn't contain anything anymore. I'd would be nice, if you'd mark this answer as correct though, if it meats your expectations, so that it can be taken as guidance by others.

Comment: I will 100% vote this as the answer. Thank you so much for continuing to help me with this problem. The solution you posted isn't exactly what I'm looking for still. I want the card (aside) to be overlaying the jumbotron, and to have the text inside the jumbotron right next to the card. When I applied the changes you made, it got rid of that effect. I am so so sorry to bother you still.

Comment: https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/eYZWJXN. Here's an example, of a general idea on how to achieve this design.

Comment: Thank you so much, this will help me out a lot. Seriously.. thank you so much. This means so much to me. I hope you have a great night.